# maven compile produces no output in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have created a new maven based java project in NetBeans. When I haven't added any dependencies, everything works fine but when I use the below given pom file (from a different project, which is similar) the run screen directly shows BUILD SUCCESS without listing any System.out.print statements or any output from the logger.

> The pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.optum.cda</groupId>
    <artifactId>cda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
    <ctakes.version>4.0.0</ctakes.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <verbose>true</verbose>
                  <executable>java</executable>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>-Xms512m</argument>
                    <argument>-Xmx512m</argument>
                    <argument>-XX:NewRatio=3</argument>
                    <argument>-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps</argument>
                    <argument>-XX:+PrintGCDetails</argument>
                    <argument>-Xloggc:gc.log</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <!--<argument>com.redstack.App</argument>-->
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- Adding cTAKES Dependecies here -->
    <dependencies>

      <!--   ctakes-core contains core classes, utilities, and commonly-used readers, writers and analysis engines.  -->
      <!--   ctakes-core will pull from maven central basic requirements: uima, uimafit, cleartk, type system ...   -->
      <!--   All other modules require ctakes-core.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-core</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-pos-tagger tags parts of speech for tokens in text.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-pos-tagger is required for ctakes-dictionary-lookup and ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-pos-tagger</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-chunker chunks tokens with parts of speech into phrases.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-chunker is required for the old ctakes-dictionary-lookup.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-chunker</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-lvg generates lexical variants of tokens in text.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-lvg</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast discovers concepts in text and normalizes them to standard codes.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast is much improved over the original ctakes-dictionary-lookup.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>      

      <!--   ctakes-assertion contains rule-based and machine-learning engines to discover entity attributes.   -->
      <!--   attributes: polarity, uncertainty, history_of, conditional, generic, subject   -->
      <!--   ctakes-assertion discovers more attributes than the ctakes-ne-contexts module.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-assertion will add ctakes-constituency-parser and ctakes-dependency-parser modules.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-assertion module requires mitre libraries that are not in maven central.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-assertion</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-ne-contexts contains rule-based engines to discover entity attributes.   -->
      <!--   attributes: polarity, status   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-ne-contexts</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-drug-ner discovers Medications and related attributes such as strength, dosage, frequency, etc.-->
      <!--   ctakes-drug-ner will add ctakes-chunker, ctakes-lvg, ctakes-dictionary-lookup,
             ctakes-context-tokenizer, ctakes-ne-contexts modules.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-drug-ner</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--   ctakes-ytex and ctakes-ytex-uima are a collection of ctakes extensions.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-ytex-uima will add ctakes-pos-tagger, ctakes-chunker, ctakes-lvg,
             ctakes-dictionary-lookup, ctakes-context-tokenizer, ctakes-constituency-parser,
             ctakes-dependency-parser, ctakes-assertion, ctakes-ne-contexts.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-ytex</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--   ctakes-clinical-pipeline contributes very little on its own, but loads many other modules.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-temporal will add ctakes-preprocessor, ctakes-pos-tagger, ctakes-chunker, ctakes-lvg,
             ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast, ctakes-context-tokenizer, ctakes-constituency-parser,
             ctakes-dependency-parser, ctakes-assertion, ctakes-ne-contexts, ctakes-drug-ner, ctakes-ytex-uima.    -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-clinical-pipeline</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--   ctakes-relation-extractor can extract relations between entities such as location and degree.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-relation-extractor will add ctakes-pos-tagger, ctakes-chunker, ctakes-lvg,
             ctakes-dictionary-lookup, ctakes-context-tokenizer, ctakes-constituency-parser,
             ctakes-dependency-parser, ctakes-ne-contexts.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-relation-extractor</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--   ctakes-temporal discovers entities, temporal expressions, temporal relations,
             and document-creation-time relativity.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-temporal will add ctakes-pos-tagger, ctakes-chunker, ctakes-lvg,
             ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast, ctakes-context-tokenizer, ctakes-constituency-parser,
             ctakes-dependency-parser, ctakes-relation-extractor, ctakes-clinical-pipeline.   -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-temporal</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--   ctakes-coreference discovers coreferent entities in text.   -->
      <!--   ctakes-coreference will add ctakes-constituency-parser, ctakes-dictionary-lookup, ctakes-assertion,
             ctakes-temporal and a large UMLS database.  -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
         <artifactId>ctakes-coreference</artifactId>
         <version>${ctakes.version}</version>
      </dependency>    

    </dependencies>
    <!-- End of cTAKES Dependencies -->

</project>
```

> The output which I get upon running my main file:

```
cd C:\Users\tdas1006\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cda; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.optum.cda.main.Test\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cda 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) @ cda ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.353s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 22 01:41:42 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the problem ??

Comment: what goals are you executing? Are you running maven from the command line or via a plugin in NetBeans?

Comment: I am using the <default config> of maven and running it using Run File option in netbeans

Comment: have you set up the goal to run when you click on the Run File option. Not very familiar with NetBeans, but in Eclipse, you need to set up the goal to run when you right click on the pom file and choose Run As -> Maven Build

Comment: @Inxsible I have edited the pom file to use maven-compiler plugin version 3.6.1. The inbuilt version of maven supplied with netbeans, which I am using is 3.0.5 ... In the output I see exec-maven-plugin has version 1.2.1. are the difference in version causing something ?? and can you point me somewhere to find out how to set up a goal

Comment: updated pom again, made goals for executing maven-exec-plugin ... now the version being used is  the one that I have defined .... but still the problem is not resolved. Any suggestions ??

Comment: @Inxsible I noticed one thing... if I remove all the dependencies from the pom file the output is show. Wonder why ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution, but I really do not understand why it works. Maybe someone could point out.

What I did was change the arguments for the maven goal to execute (org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec). Previously it was using java to execute the classes which was causing the problem. When I switched to using javaw instead of java as the executable everything works normal, I don't know why !

I changed the nbactions.xml file to include javaw in the goals. The edited file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
        <action>
            <actionName>run</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>run.single.main</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>*</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
                <exec.classpathScope>${classPathScope}</exec.classpathScope>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>debug</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
                <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>debug.single.main</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>*</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
                <exec.classpathScope>${classPathScope}</exec.classpathScope>
                <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>profile</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>profile.single.main</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>*</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>javaw</exec.executable>
                <exec.classpathScope>${classPathScope}</exec.classpathScope>
            </properties>
        </action>
    </actions>
```

Comment: Where is this nbactions.xml file located?